# why is it saying No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, cors, plesk

why am i getting this error from CORS policy ?

error:
[image]

although I have added the middleware function for CORS :
[image]

Am I missing something here  to add?

Comment: because the preflight has no CORS headers - at least, that's what the error states

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)